# Fourier Transform get about half the outputs wrong

Tags: java, arrays, audio, fft

My project plays music and constantly writes the "intensity" of the bass into a text file. However, about half of the intensities are wrong, meaning my fourier transform output is janked up or something. It causes an output like this: http://pastebin.com/yxyBwv2Q Where all the bars should line up. There are 3 different tones in that pastebin, in the order of (3,1,2) regarding how hard they are hitting. That makes sense, the project definitely shows when and only when the bass is hitting hard. It's just not smooth at all, there's an error margin.

This is the code:

```
    package script;
import javazoom.jl.decoder.BitstreamException;
import javazoom.jl.decoder.Decoder;
import javazoom.jl.decoder.DecoderException;
import javazoom.jl.decoder.Header;
import javazoom.jl.decoder.JavaLayerException;
import javazoom.jl.decoder.Obuffer;
import javazoom.jl.decoder.SampleBuffer;
import javazoom.jl.decoder.Bitstream;
import javazoom.jl.player.Player;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;

import org.tritonus.share.sampled.file.TAudioFileFormat;

import edu.emory.mathcs.jtransforms.fft.DoubleFFT_1D;

public class MusicPlayer {
    static double getDurationWithMp3Spi(File file)
            throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException {

        AudioFileFormat fileFormat = AudioSystem.getAudioFileFormat(file);
        if (fileFormat instanceof TAudioFileFormat) {
            Map<?, ?> properties = ((TAudioFileFormat) fileFormat).properties();
            String key = "duration";
            Long microseconds = (Long) properties.get(key);
            int mili = (int) (microseconds / 1000);
            int sec = (mili / 1000);
            int min = (mili / 1000) / 60;
            return microseconds / 1000000.0;
        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedAudioFileException();}
        }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            JavaLayerException, InterruptedException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, AWTException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //E:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\SteamApps\\common\\team fortress 2\\tf\\cfg\\script.cfg

        FileInputStream mp3 = new FileInputStream("30hz.mp3");
        FileInputStream mp3player = new FileInputStream("30hz.mp3");
        File song = new File("30hz.mp3");
        Decoder decoder = new Decoder();
        Bitstream bitstream = new Bitstream(mp3);
        Bitstream playerBitstream = new Bitstream(mp3player);
        SampleBuffer currentBuffer = (SampleBuffer) decoder.decodeFrame(
                bitstream.readFrame(), bitstream);
        Player player = new Player(mp3player);
        int bufferLength = currentBuffer.getBufferLength();
        DoubleFFT_1D transform = new DoubleFFT_1D(bufferLength);
        double duration = getDurationWithMp3Spi(song);
        bitstream.unreadFrame();
        bitstream.closeFrame();
        String fov;
        int x =0;
        int placeholder=0;
        double currentMaximum=Double.MIN_VALUE;
        double maximum=20000;
        int freq=0;
        Robot robot = new Robot();

        String text=" ";
        String[] textAmp = new String[200];
        for(int i=0;i<200;i++){
            textAmp[i]="O";
            for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
                textAmp[i]=textAmp[i]+"O";
            }
        }
        player.play(1);
        player.play(1);
        player.play(1);
        player.play(1);
        player.play(1);
        player.play(1);
        player.play(1);
        player.play(1);
        player.play(1);
        player.play(1);
        double intensity=0;
        while (((x <= (int) (((44100 * (duration - 1)) / 1152.0))))) {
            player.play(1);

            currentBuffer = (SampleBuffer) decoder.decodeFrame(bitstream.readFrame(), bitstream);
            short[] originalBufferArray = new short[bufferLength];
            originalBufferArray = currentBuffer.getBuffer();
            double[] doubleBufferArray = new double[bufferLength*2];
            for(int i =0; i<bufferLength;i++){
                doubleBufferArray[i]=(double)originalBufferArray[i];
            }
            double temp=0;
            //BEGIN ARRAYLIST
//          double[] organizedArray = new double[2304];
//          for(int i=0;i<1152;i++){
//              organizedArray[i*2]=doubleBufferArray[i];
//          }
//          for(int i=1152;i<2304;i++){
//              organizedArray[((i-1152)*2)+1]=doubleBufferArray[i];
//          }
            //END ARRAYLIST
            transform.complexForward(doubleBufferArray,0);
            double[] finalArray = new double[bufferLength];

            for(int i =0;i<10;i+=2){
                finalArray[i/2]= Math.sqrt(Math.pow(doubleBufferArray[i],2)+(Math.pow(doubleBufferArray[i+1], 2)));
                finalArray[i/2]= finalArray[i/2]/(double)(bufferLength/2.0);
                if(finalArray[i/2]>currentMaximum){
                    currentMaximum=finalArray[i/2];
                    freq=i/2;
                }
            }
//               if (freq==4){
//                  currentMaximum/=4;
//                  intensity=currentMaximum/maximum;
//                  
//              }
//              else if (freq==3){
//                  currentMaximum/=3;
//                  intensity=currentMaximum/maximum;
//              }
//              else if (freq==2){
//                  currentMaximum/=2;
//                  intensity=currentMaximum/maximum;
//              }
//              else{
                    intensity=currentMaximum/maximum;
                    int fovInt=(int)(90-(intensity*25));

            //  }



//          text=String.valueOf(intensity);
//          text=text.substring(2,4);
//          placeholder = (int)Double.parseDouble(text);
                    try{
                    File script = new File("E:\\Program Files (x86)\\Steam\\SteamApps\\common\\team fortress 2\\tf\\cfg\\script.cfg");
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(script));
                    fov = "fov_desired " + fovInt +"\necho \"working\"";
            writer.write(fov, 0 ,fov.length());
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();

            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_NUM_LOCK );
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_NUM_LOCK );
                    } finally{}
            currentMaximum=Double.MIN_VALUE;
            bitstream.unreadFrame();
            bitstream.closeFrame();
            x++;
            }

/*
 * 0~0hz
 * 1~19.140625hz
 * 2~38.28125hz
 * 3~57.422145hz
 * 4~76.56277
 * 5~ 95.703395
 */




    }
        }
```

Anyone know why my Fourier analysis is getting me weird results? Also the plays at the start are so the songs sync with the output.

Answer (score 0):

For short FFTs that are not synchronized to the waveform, there will be some scalloping of the magnitude depending on the phase of the input signal relative to the window's edges.  Making the FFT longer, perhaps many periods of your low frequency in length, will minimize this, as will using a non-rectangular window (Von Hann, etc.).  For 40 Hz, you might try an FFT that is at least 8192 samples (roughly 8 periods of 43 Hz) in length, or longer.

Comment: Ah ok, I'll try that then. Is there a certain threshold, like say 8192, that will get all the low frequencies exactly right? Or should i just take the max, 44100? i imagine that the more i take the slower my program will be, as for 44100 it would ony process one second of data at a time. And I'm confused, is there any way to get all 21050 frequencies quickly in a song? I seem to only be able to get 1152 frequencies.

Comment: There is no exact number of all frequencies. For instance, some sound's spectral component could be at 261.63 Hz.  The longer the FFT, the more resulting frequency bins, thus resolution, you get.